# Updating related table data MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm working on an MVC 4 application and I'm wondering what's the best way to update data of related tables.

I have two tables related to each other with a Foreign Key...a one-to-many relationship:

**Table: Payrolls**

```
ID

PayrollDate

CompanyId

IsProcessed

IsComplete
```

**Table: PayrollDocuments**

```
ID

DocumentUrl

UserId

PayrollId (FK)

IsApproved
```

I have a `View` which displays the `PayrollDocuments` of a `Payroll`, as seen below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.PayrollDocuments.Count; i++)
{            
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.PayrollDocuments[i].ID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.PayrollDocuments[i].DocumentUrl)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.PayrollDocuments[i].UserId)

    PayrollDocument pd = Model.PayrollDocuments[i];
    <div class="editor-label">
        @pd.User.FirstName @pd.User.LastName
    </div>

    <a href="@pd.DocumentUrl" target="_blank">@pd.DocumentUrl</a><br />

    @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.PayrollDocuments[i].IsApproved)
}
```

This `View` enables a user to Approve the `PayrollDocuments` added for a particular `Payroll`. The issue is that passing the Payroll object to update both tables is only updating the `Payroll` table.

```
// update payroll
public Payroll UpdatePayroll(Payroll p)
{
   try
   {
        Payroll _p = GetPayroll(p.ID);

        this.Entity.Entry(_p).CurrentValues.SetValues(p);
        this.Entity.SaveChanges();

        return p;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
        throw ex;
   }
}
```

What I had to do is loop through the `PayrollDocuments` list and update them one by one. I'm just curious if this is normal practice. When updating a `Payroll` object to add `PayrollDocument` to the database it worked with no issues. I can't really understand why updating it is not working without having to loop through all the objects.

Comment: The only data being passed to `UpdatePayroll` is a `Payroll` object, so that's all that's getting updated.  Any other changes outside that one object (such as setting a property on multiple other objects) would need to be done manually in that logic.  Unless I'm not understanding the problem fully?  Unrelated Note: Your `catch` block is (1) superfluous and (2) throwing away useful exception information.  It should just be removed entirely.

Comment: Yes the `Payroll` object is being passed, however this object has a list of `PayrollDocuments`. While debugging `PayrollDocument` properties are updated but they are never reflected in the database. Unless going through the list and updating every list item one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it manually as you are doing for the Payroll object. Only this way the entity framework knows what to do with the PayrollDocuments. If you are in a HTTP context you get your Payroll object disconnected from any database repository. You have to explicitly add them to the repository and define what operation that should be take for each object.